# How to combine 2 MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

I was wondering how can I combine these two queries.

Here is the MySQL queries.

```
 SELECT COUNT(user_id) as users, user_id
 FROM users_text
 GROUP BY user_id


 SELECT SUM(grade_points) as 'points'
 FROM grades
 ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: your second query will only return a single row. how do you want to combine them? what's the relation between `grades` and `users_text`? do you want the sum of points per user?

Comment: these are two different queries yeilding two different results, would you clarify on what you mean by combining them?

Comment: are the users_test and grades a related in a way? Do they have a common field?

Comment: I just want one query instead of coding two queries

Comment: @codester: those are two different queries, you can't simply combine them, if they (or the result) is not related in any way

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest an UNHOLY_UNION query. Useless, yes; Confusing, yes; Just a single query, also yes ;)

Of course, without knowing more about the relations between the tables, this is all just groping in the darkness.

Answer (score 2):

**No, you cannot**, cause you have two totally separated queries - therefor you won't be able to combine these using **JOIN**.

For that they need to have at least one common field.

Answer (score 1):

i assume here you want to sum up the points per user:

```
  SELECT user_id, SUM(grade_points) as 'points'
    FROM grades
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY points DESC
```

Comment: I would go with this one if the table structure reflects this query, even though it is not clear from the question.

Comment: @DrColossos: yes, table structure would be quite some help

Answer (score 1):

I would try this (assuming grades table has a user_id column)

```
 SELECT COUNT(user_id) as users, user_id, (SELECT SUM(g.grade_points)  FROM grades g WHERE g.user_id = user_id ) as 'points'
 FROM users_text
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: "assuming grades table has a user_id column" - this seems to be not the case here

Comment: you've got a point, but if this is not the case then i totally do not understand why he wants to combine the queries :)